# Integrating Laravel Application into Wordpress inside Plugin Panel (Admin)

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, custom-wordpress-pages

I need to develop a business CMS with additional custom portal for ticketing etc. For the CMS part, choosing WordPress seemed convenient as it's very good (for what it is for, i.e. CMS) and my client knows how to use it.

When you add a plugin to WordPress, in admin panel it shows a tab (or link for the plugin settings), so I thought my code could be integrated this way. I am familiar and comfortable with Laravel so I thought there could be a link in the navigation bar to my Laravel application which will use WordPress authentication (like [this method](http://nehalist.io/integrating-laravel-into-wordpress/)).

1- Is this bad practice?

2- Is there any easier method?

3- Is it possible to write RESTful api in Laravel and integrate into WP? Is this better?

4- Is there a plugin to wrap Laravel into Wordpress as a plugin?

---

Edit: What I meant for 'custom plugin panel':

[image]

Comment: Maybe this? https://github.com/jumilla/wordpress-plus

Comment: I wanted to add Laravel into a subfolder on my site, which is built with Joomla, so www.example.com was Joomla and www.example.com/classes was my php framework. Originally I wanted to design a 'plugin' for joomla but that was too complicated for me at the time... I ended up having to go with codeigniter because installing laravel on my host in a subfolder using the command line was too complicated. I am interested to hear is this is considered 'bad' practice.

Comment: Wordpress plus is not exactly what I am looking for because its integrating Wordpress into Laravel.. What i am up to is integrating Laravel into Wordpress (and be able to access it as a tab as part of the admin page and overall system)

Comment: why dont you use a laravel based cms somethng like october cms

Comment: I added a screenshot in question to clarify what I want to achieve...

Comment: Does *Custom Laravel Package* need to appear in the WP Dashboard? Or act as a link?

Comment: _Custom Laravel Package_ need to appear in WP Dashboard.. When you add a new plugin to WP (in admin panel), it adds a new plugin panel to tabs on the left and when you click it, it brings you the settings of that plugin.. In this page, what I want to return is the blade (view) created by Laravel so I can use my custom app within the WP dashboard. (Please check above screenshot where it shows welcome page of Laravel)

Comment: How far along are you with this project? Id like to hear back from you if you got through with the current solution or found a better alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a php file within your `/wp-content/plugins` directory with the following content and enable the plugin from `WP Admin Panel>Installed Plugins` you get the result

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Custom Plugin
*/

add_action('admin_menu', 'custom_plugin');

function custom_plugin() {
    add_menu_page('Custom Plugin', 'Custom Plugin', 'manage_options', 'test_plugin', 'custom_plugin_menu', '', 2);
}

function custom_plugin_menu() {
    echo 'test';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install this plugin https://github.com/golr/wl-bootstrap.

Don't need to move Laravel project directory in to Wordpress directory.

and then You can use any functions like Helpers, Session, Authentication, Eloquent in Wordpress code.

Comment: I just tried this but not working. It's only working on my localhost :(